# When does Rails 3.2 reach end of life?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Now that Rails 4.2 has been released, has Rails 3.2 released end of life? If not, does anyone know when Rails 3.2 is EOL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails 3.2 will be completely abandoned once Rails 5.0 is released (sometime in 2015, no fixed date). That said, the 3.2 version already receives only *severe* security fixes and as such I'd strongly recommend to upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Correct. That appears to be the case, looking at their maintenance policy: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/maintenance_policy.html

Comment: Just curious, has their been any official documentation saying 3.2 will be completely abandoned when 5.0 is out? Or is this based on their published maintenance policy page?

Comment: I guess the 4.2 release notes makes the timeline clear: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2014/12/19/Rails-4-2-final/ -- Summer 2015

Answer (score 5):

Ruby on Rails 3.2 reached its end of life-cycle with the release of [Rails 5.0](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2016/6/30/Rails-5-0-final/) on June 30th, 2016.

We still saw some security fixes after that date (like [3.2.22.5](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/3.2.22.5) in September 2016), but these were exceptions. And you should not expect any further version.

If you still run an application on Rails 4.2.x or below it is highly recommended to update to 5.2.x with a high priority.

[Rails' Maintenance Policy](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/maintenance_policy.html) makes it quite clear when a version should be considered un-maintained.

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason you're stuck for now on Rails 3.2 or 2.3, railslts.com offers long term support for security patches for these rails versions.

In our case, an application that's being replaced can't justify the upgrade time. In the meantime while it's up, this service is perfect.